# TypeError in Ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, routes, laravel-5

I'm getting the following error on Ajax call in Laravel 5:

TypeError: 'stepUp' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLInputElement.

> d=[],e=function(a,b){b=n.isFunction(b)?b():null==b?"":b,

The form is as follows:

```
<form id="comment_form">
    <input type="textarea" class="form-control_comment" id="comment" placeholder="Type your comment here...">
    <input type="hidden" name="uid" id="uid" value="{{$user->id}}">
    <input type="hidden" name="pid" id="pid" value="{{$post->id}}">
    <input type="hidden" id="token" value="{{$csrf_token()}}">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" id= "comment_button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The Ajax part:

```
<script>

   $("#comment_button").click(function(e){


             e.preventDefault();
             var token = $("#token").val();
             var a= $("#comment").val();
             var uid= $("#uid").val();
             var url = "<?php echo Request::root();?>";



            $.ajax({

                url: url+"post/comment_action",
                type: "POST",
                async: false,
                data: {newComment:a, uid:uid, pid:pid, _token: token},

                success: function (newResult){


                    if(newResult!="")
                    {
                        newResult= JSON.parse(newResult);
                        $("#all_responses").append(newResult);
                    }


                }
            }).error(function()
            {
                alert("Error");
            });

        });

</script>
```

in routes.php:

```
Route::post('post/comment_action', array('as'=>'post/comment_action', 'uses'=>'PostController@postComment_action'));
```

And the action part in PostController:

```
 public function postComment_action()
{

    if(Auth::check())
    {
        if(Request::ajax())
        {
            $inputs= Input::all();

        }

        $new_comment= $inputs['newComment'];
        $uid= $inputs['uid'];
        $pid= $inputs['pid'];
        $com= new Comment;
        $com->content= $new_comment;
        $com->userId= $uid;
        $com->postId= $pid;
        $com->save();

        $data= array();

        $all_comments= Comment::where('postId', $pid)->first();
        $u= User::where('id', $uid);

        foreach($all_comments as $coms)
        {
            $data= $coms->content;
        }

        $data= json_encode($data);
        echo $data;
    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect::route('signin_user')->withErrors("You must sign in to perform this action");
    }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)